# Must a kiddush cup be both clean and dry?

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, kiddush

The kiddush cup needs washing inside and out ([O Ch 183:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.183?lang=bi)).

The hands need to be washed before eating bread. One may not eat bread with wet hands – it is like eating impure bread according to the Shulchan Oruch [O Ch 158 (12)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.158?lang=bi).

Is there any requirement to dry the kiddush cup so that one is not drinking “impure wine”?

Comment: What does the kiddush cup have to do with bread. The rule of bread applies to all bread; regardless of shabbat. Do you think that one can never drink from a wet cup? Why would a kisdush cup be different?

Comment: Mi.yodeya.com/a/26255

Comment: how does one drink from a dry cup? as soon as you pour wine into it the cup becomes wet. why would it matter if it was wet before hand?

Comment: @Laser123 The question relates to the cup being wet on the outside.